# decay rate of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, exponential

I want to know how quickly some data returns to baseline after an initial peak (here at ca `x=5`);

The quadratic fit looks about right (from the figures option of matlab, shown below) - but I'm looking for a **concise quantification of this curve**, therefore I presume the '[decay rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay)' of the exponential function would be one very straightforward.

1. Is this assumption correct?
2. If yes, I looked at the formula on wiki for this, and attempted shamelessly to find a solve for the time constant (but unsuccessfully so). Can someone help me out, or is this actually a not so trivial problem?

edit: I was planning to find the peak using MathWorks' `findpeaks()` function, and the lowest point of the curve using the 'inverse' `findpeaks()` (as in: `-y`)

[image]

```
%approx data values of the curves below
y= [0   0.07    0.08    0.08    0.08    0.06    0.06    0.05    0.04    0.05    0.04    0.02    0.01    0.02    0.01    0.01    0.03    0.02    0.02    0.02    0.03    0.01    0.02    0.01    0.01    0.03    0.02    0.01    0.02    0.01];
x=1:numel(y);
plot(x,y);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: First you need to remove the up step, since this does not fit the exponential decay curve.

Comment: Then you have two options... a direct non-linear curve fit (it's monotonic so it will be quite efficient) -- using e.g. `lsqnonlin` -- or a linear fit of `log(y)`, which is really easy but represents a very different assumption about the sampling error than the usual AWGN model.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I understand that, about the removing up step, I can do this easily with findpeaks in matlab, this works wonderfully. Unfortunately I have no clue about the lsqnonlin and AWGN models =/

Comment: I should probably also mention that I have very basic math skills, essentially I do not know how to interpret differential equations.

Comment: I think `lsqnonlin` basically solves this question (see exact example [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#buuhcjf-2)), at least on first approximation of skimming the documentation on it, if you think others can profit please elaborate in an answer, then I'll accept. I should mention this function requires the optimisation toolbox that I don't have access to currently

Comment: Your data do not follow a specific physical law ? Or a well known equation ? It's always an advantage to know a priori the equation that have generated your data, because you could directly fit your noisy data with the right equation/physical law.

Comment: @obchardon I think all that can be assumed it's exponentially decaying data. A typical publication cites methods (this is biology, so it's not the focus) like this: [constant] was determined from a
single exponential fit to the fluorescence decay.

Comment: @user2305193 Ho ok, then an exponential fit seems to be the right option. Good job =)

Comment: @obchardon I should have probably mentioned that this is about calcium sensors and their fluorescence decay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two options I was looking for, maybe someone can elaborate / improve this answer about the differences for these approaches - for me this is good enough, thanks for the comments. Before this step, using the data provided in the example of the question, the local maximum and minimum has to be extracted, this can be done easily using `findpeaks()`

approach 1) requires the curve toolbox from Matlab [[Source]](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/exponential.html#bs41m8u-1)

```
%Fit a Single-Term Exponential Model, copy from Mathworks documentation, all credits go there
x = (0:0.2:5)';
y = 2*exp(-0.2*x) + 0.1*randn(size(x));
f = fit(x,y,'exp1')
f = 
     General model Exp1:
     f(x) = a*exp(b*x)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =       2.021  (1.89, 2.151)
       b =     -0.1812  (-0.2104, -0.152)
plot(f,x,y)
```

[image]

or approach 2) requires the optimizaion toolbox from Matlab [[Source]](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#buuhcjf-2)

```
%copy from Mathworks documentation, all credits go there
rng default % for reproducibility
d = linspace(0,3);
y = exp(-1.3*d) + 0.05*randn(size(d));
fun = @(r)exp(-d*r)-y;
x0 = 4;
x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0)
plot(d,y,'ko',d,exp(-x*d),'b-')
legend('Data','Best fit')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('exp(-tx)')
```

[image]